# Why is 7-Zip better than the Windows 10 default file compressor?

Tags: windows-10, compression, 7-zip

7-Zip is significantly faster than Windows 10 at compressing files, it is more effective (smaller outputs), and is better at estimating time to completion/progress.

How can it be that with all of Microsoft's infrastructure they have a very visible, mediocre algorithm in their newest main product?

Answer (score 2):

Because the builtin version is "good enough" for most people, and uses a standard algorithm and encoding that basically any Windows based computer > Windows95 computer can understand.

Those that need better compression can get a dedicated compression tool.

Comment: Windows compression must work under some severe constraints. It must support applications accessing arbitrary locations in a file and reading uncompressed data and it must do this quickly. This is a very common situation. The application need not be aware that the file is compressed. This works and well. The user is typically unaware of any added delays. 7-zip works only with entire files. To access data in the file it must first be entirely decompressed and with large files that is going to be very time consuming.